# CSS - Parent <a> is smaller than child

Tags: html, css

I have a panel. Which looks like this:

[image]

It's not best, but its a copy of things I have in a PSD. The problem is that when you check HTML `<a>` is before image display and it still make `<a>` as `0x0px`, the problem is with all 3 images in that panel and I don't know how to fix it. Can somebody help me to make each `<a>` to be as big as that image and button are?

**HTML:**

```
<section class="panel">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/right_banner.png"> </a>
    <a href="#"><div class="panel_button"><span class="text">NAHLÁSIT CHEATERA</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="panel_button"><span class="text">CW/TG REZERVACE</span></div></a>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.panel {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 13px;      
}

.panel a {
    width: 201px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;     
}   

.panel_button {
    background-image: url("images/panel_blue_button.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 198px;
    height: 93px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 16px;
}

.panel_button span{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

**[Live preview](http://funedit.com/andurit/new)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor element is currently an `inline` element. You could change it to either `block` or `inline-block` to achieve the desired results.

```
.panel > a {
    display: block;
}
```